# Coinbase Websocket AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, api, websocket, collections, coinbase-api

So I'm using python 3.10.1 and to my uderstanding the module isn't compatible with this version as it results in the error

```
Coinbase Websocket AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I downloaded python 3.9.0 using pyenv, and created a virtual env. The websocket seems to work now, but It had me wondering if the module will be working in 3.10 soon as well?

Is there already a way to work around the problem as I would prefer to work in python 3.10?

full code

```
import cbpro

'''establish a live data feed from coinbase'''

class TextWebsocketClient(cbpro.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.url = 'wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'
        self.message_count = 0


    def on_message(self, msg):
        self.message_count += 1
        msg_type = msg.get('type', None)
        if msg_type == 'ticker':
            time_val = msg.get('time',('-'*27))
            price_val = msg.get('price', None)
            price_val = float(price_val) if price_val is not None else 'None'
            product_id = msg.get('product_id', None)

            print(f'{time_val:30} {price_val:3f} {product_id}\tchannel type: {msg_type}')

    def on_close(self):
        print(f'<---Websocket client closed --->\n\tTotal messages exchanged {self.messages.count}')

'''call the client'''

stream = TextWebsocketClient(products=['BTC-USD'], channels=['ticker'])
stream.start()
```